# delete row based on a condition

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am coding in C# and using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. I am have columns A-F and some rows don't have any value in column B. So I want to loop through column B and find all cells with no text/value and then delete that entire row.
I manged to loop through column B and find the null cell, but then when I try to delete that row- nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
Excel.Range B = objsheet.get_Range("B1:B" + lastUsedRow, System.Type.Missing);
foreach (Excel.Range r in B)
{
    string column = r.Text.ToString();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(column))
    {
        Excel.Range BEntireRow = objsheet.get_Range(r + "1:" + r + "B" + lastUsedColumn, System.Type.Missing);
        //  Excel.Range BEntireRow2 = r.EntireRow;
        BEntireRow.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);

    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than looping through the column you can do the following; this is the VBA code:

```
Range("B1:B" + lastUsedRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

In C# you would use:

```
.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks)
```

BTW I wouldn't name your Excel.Application object `Excel` - I would use xl or even myXl. It is confusing otherwise, and may cause errors at some point.

**Added** The full C# statement would be

```
Range("B1:B" + lastUsedRow).SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete();
```

Comment: what does this do? .SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks) - delete the cells?

Comment: whats wrong with this: Excel.Range BEntireRow =  objsheet.get_Range("B1:B" + lastUsedRow, System.Type.Missing);
                    BEntireRow.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete;

Comment: any solution- im not clear on the full implementation of your code

Comment: I've added a full C# statement to my answer but if you don't know how to implement this in your code then I'm afraid you'll need to back-track and study (C# first, then Excel).

Comment: Part of the reason that your code (in your recent comment) wouldn't work is that `Delete` is a method and requires parentheses in C# - `Delete()`.

Comment: thanks! I used part of your solution. Delete() needs parameters so I split that into a new line:Excel.Range BEntireRow = objsheet.get_Range("B1:B" + lastUsedRow, System.Type.Missing).SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks, 4);
            Excel.Range deletecells = BEntireRow.EntireRow;
            deletecells.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Rows([INSERT_THE_ROW_YOU_WANT_TO_DELETE_HERE]).EntireRow.Delete;
```

Comment: add a dot before `EntireRow` :D

Comment: please, its like bugging me to death and I cant edit only 1 character